# How to use update Qlabel with jpg using QNetworkRequest?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtgui, qtnetwork, qt-signals

I am using PyQt4 to create a form which displays a web based image in a separate window using a Qlabel. It should be that clicking a button on the form updates the Qlabel with a new image by reading the new image url from a table cell on the form.

The issue I think I am having is not understanding how to create the Qlabel as a class object which I can then update by setting its setPixmap() property. Here's what I've written so far:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest


CAT_PICS = ["http://static.tumblr.com/ce35b04e242c6b8073f3ff7801147e9f/sz5wgey/obSmpcvso/tumblr_static_o-cats-kill-billions-facebook.jpg",
        "http://jasonlefkowitz.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/cats-16140154-1920-1080.jpg",
        "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-MzZCzWI_6Xc/UIUQp1qPfzI/AAAAAAAAHpA/OTwHCJSWFAY/s1600/cats_animals_kittens_cat_kitten_cute_desktop_1680x1050_hd-wallpaper-753974.jpeg"]


class ImageLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QLabel.__init__(self, parent)

        url = self.text()
        nam = QNetworkAccessManager()
        def finishRequest(reply):
            img = QImage()
            img.loadFromData(reply.readAll())
            myImage = QPixmap(img)

            self.setFixedSize(myImage.size())
            self.setPixmap(QPixmap(myImage))
        nam.finished.connect(finishRequest)
        nam.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)))



class MainForm(QDialog):
    index = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__()

        changePhotoButton = QPushButton("Next Photo")
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(changePhotoButton)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.connect(changePhotoButton, SIGNAL("clicked()"),
                     self.updatePhoto)


    def updatePhoto(self):
        url = CAT_PICS[self.index]
        imageLabel = ImageLabel(url)
        imageLabel.show()
        self.index += 1

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
main()
```

The code will run, however when the ImageLabel class is called the QLabel is created with the initial text from the url but the image is never fetched and the Qlabel is removed from view immediately.

I would appreciate any tips on how to get this working.

Comment: Why are you making a QLabel subclass for this operation?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to make it so that the initial form can update the Qlabel by clicking the button. So far I can get a Qlabel with image created by placing the code inside the ImageLabel class in main() I can't get it to work by placing it anywhere else. I don't know how to handle the `nam.finished.connect(finishRequest)` and `def finishRequest(reply):` parts.

Comment: You really do not need a subclass for this. You can connect the button click to a slot which sets the corresponding pixmap... Also, you use `imageLabel = ImageLabel(url)` whereas the ImageLabel class does not have such an "__init__" method parameter... OT: "main()" as a line looks strange in python.

Comment: "I don't know how to handle the nam.finished.connect(finishRequest) and def finishRequest(reply): parts." -> What exactly is your concern in there?

Comment: Could you write some example code as I am not familiar with slots? I'm not really familiar with the syntax for  `nam.finished.connect(finishRequest)` or `def finishRequest(reply)`  and couldn't see a clear explanation so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, I would drop the custom QLabel subclass and would extend the updatePhoto method instead as demonstrated below. However, it seems that you did not handle the url correctly.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.myLabel = QLabel()
    self.nam = QNetworkAccessManager()
    self.nam.finished.connect(self.finishRequest)
    ...

def finishRequest(self, reply):
    myPixmap = QPixmap()
    if not myPixmap.loadFromData(reply.readAll()):
        print('Could not load')
    self.myLabel.setFixedSize(myImage.size())
    self.myLabel.setPixmap(myPixmap)
    self.myLabel.show()

def updatePhoto(self):
    url = CAT_PICS[self.index]
    self.nam.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)))
    self.index += 1
```

Note that I would use the nam and myLabel as class members of your correponding python class.

Comment: Hi, yes the url should be type QUrl and not str, thanks for correcting. I am confused about a few things with your answer. By making nam and myLabel class members does that mean to declare them in the MainForm class so that they are accessible via self.nam and self.myLabel?

Comment: @wanyo: yes, I updated the answer, apologies. I was having a C++ mindset last night, not python'ish. ;-)

Comment: What I meant to ask was, how does one go about making nam and myLabel class members? If I try to declare them under MainForm class so that they are accessible via self.nam and self.myLabel I get an error saying that I must construct a QApplication before using a QPaintDevice. Also after adding the finishRequest(reply) method to the Mainform class and making your edits to updatePhoto() I get the problem that finishRequest is undefined and that method finishRequest() should have self as a first parameter.

Comment: I realised that I should probably be declaring nam and mLabel under the constructor section of the MainForm class and not outside it. This removes the problem with the QApplicaton before QPaintDevice. I think the problem is now how to properly declare and call finishRequest as currently it has no access to myLabel. I will update my original question with the changes. Thanks.

Comment: @wanyo: I am not sure I understand the question. If it is a class member, you have access to myLabel as the methods can access class members. Admittedly, it should be self.finishRequest for the connection though. I will edit that typo later with other issues if they come up. OT: there is no constructor in python, at least in the python sense, but yes, the init method looks like a valid place for it since that is only evaluated when instantiated, not for the module loading when it is outside.

Comment: I initially thought to declare myLabel outside the __init__ method which was causing python to have a fit. I've moved the declarations inside the __init__ method where I've added `self.myLabel = QLabel()` and `self.nam = QNetworkManager()`. These can be accessed now in the updatePhoto method but the finishRequest method currently has no way of accessing them. I don't understand what is going on when calling self.finishRequest, what is the replay parameter used in the method and why is it not needed to be given when calling it?

Comment: @wanyo: please read this, http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html You may need the pyqtSlot() decorator for the method for being complete.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll have a read and see what sense I can make of it. I thought I should say that I have managed to load an image by making a small change by adding the self parameter to finishRequest(**self**, reply): The first image successfully loads when clicking the button. But on subsequent clicks something strange happens in the finishRequest method and it fails to load further images. I did get it to load the 3rd image on the third click but now it just fails, printing the debug text "Could not load" once after the second click and then twice after the third.

Comment: Ah, yes, self is needed... that is again a C++ mindset from last night.... It is sometimes hard to make the context switch. :-) If it fails to laod, check the formats if you have all the imageformat plugins installed. It seems only the third is jpeg, so that might be the reason why it loads, but the previous jpgs do not. http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qimage.html#reading-and-writing-image-files

Comment: The context switch makes it hard when looking for PyQt examples to follow too :) I've tried with various images and I have verified they are jpg. The strange behaviour seems to be coming from the line `myPixMap.loadFromData(reply.readAll())`. If I simplify the program by just fetching the first url when clicking the button. And watch what is going on in the finishRequest method then I see that on the first call, a valid QPixmap is created and given a value, but on subsequent button press the finishRequest seems to be getting called multiple times and it's value is being given then set to NULL

Comment: @wanyo: ah, gosh, move this line into the init method: self.nam.finished.connect(finishRequest)

Comment: Perfect, that fixed it. Could you please explain what on earth was going on and why the finishRequest method was being called multiple times? Could we update your answer with the solution for the benefit of future PyQt learners. Thank you for sticking with this.

Comment: @wanyo: done. You connected the signal to the slot once more for every button click, so for each new button click there was always one more call... So, it was one slot call, then two, then three, etc... and since the first time it is when you read the reply all, for the subsequent slot calls, there was no data to read, hence no proper QPixmap to build up.